# php multiple index array (dynamically generate atleas 300 index have ) inside add one element without using loop

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array (atleast this array in 400 index), this result i getting from mysql query

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [admission_no] => 6757
        [status] => failure
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [admission_no] => 4254
        [status] => failure
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [admission_no] => 4254
        [status] => success
    )

)
```

But i need this anaswer without looping

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [admission_no] => 6757
        [status] => failure
        [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri //this element newly added
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [admission_no] => 4254
        [status] => failure
        [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [admission_no] => 4254
        [status] => success
        [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri
    )

)
```

Comment: `array_walk` my be what you are looking for. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = array(array( 'id'=> 2,
        'admission_no' => 4254,
        'status' => 'failure'
    ),array( 'id'=> 3,
        'admission_no' => 4254,
        'status' => 'failure'
    ),array( 'id'=> 4,
        'admission_no' => 4254,
        'status' => 'failure'
    ));
array_walk($arr, function (&$value) {
    $value[0] = 'TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri';
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [admission_no] => 4254
            [status] => failure
            [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [admission_no] => 4254
            [status] => failure
            [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [admission_no] => 4254
            [status] => failure
            [0] => TVIS Velammal Vidyalaya, Ponneri
        )

)
```

Comment: HI thans for suggestion. But for and array_walk take same time execution,
give me any other solutions